# Refactoring in SpringSource Tool Suite produces non-working code

Tags: spring, refactoring, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

If I rename classes with Refactor->Rename in STS, class references are automatically updated (like in a normal Eclipse Java project), *but not* in special Spring files like the XML configuration files (e.g. `root-context.xml`) which specify things like dependency injections. This results in non-working code.

Anybody knows how this problem is supposed to be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable the option "Update fully qualified names in non-Java text files."

This is an option in the "Rename Type" dialog.
It occures if you press refactor name (Alt-Shift+R) TWICE!

Comment: Thanks. Where do I find this option?

Comment: @user1035411: see my extended answer: twice: Alt-Shift+R

Comment: Thanks. It was hidden very well.