# While importing maven projects showing project name in small - sts

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have some projects and those project names are in capital letters. I have to install maven dependency so by right-clicking on that project I choose 'Import maven projects' then that project name is showing in project explorer in small letters.

But, it should be in a capital letter like the previous one.

`TFLEX_PROJECT1 -> Import maven project ->  tflex_project1` ( coming after importing)

What configuration I have done wrong in STS so it is showing like that?

If anyone is facing this issue please let me know the configuration.

Comment: Please check value of artifactId`<artifactId>tflex_project1</artifactId>` in pom.xml file. I think value of artifactId is in lowercase for your project.

Comment: Yes ... If i change the value there is an error occuring i can't change the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should not define the package name in capital letters.** The STS is working as per java standards. but if you still want to change the project name to uppercase then consider **Refactoring-> Rename** it will automatically update the project name in all locations (like pom.xml/package name in every class).

Comment: Where i can get the Refactoring option

Comment: I don't have sts now but look for Code or rename option even in right click also it may show  [Refer this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9173812/refactoring-in-springsource-tool-suite-produces-non-working-code)

Answer (score 2):

Look for the name in pom.xml. The project name must have in lowercase in pom.xml

Comment: Yes ... if i change the name  and save. It is not changing the project name

Comment: reload the maven